# Possible performance change if column NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX will be Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

If column is declared as `NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX`, will making it `PRIMARY KEY` do any actual change on performance or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not have any effect. To within a few handwaves<sup>1</sup>, a `PRIMARY KEY` is the same as a `UNIQUE KEY`, with the additional proviso that all columns are forced to be non-NULL. As such, decorating this column as the PRIMARY KEY should not result in any change in the physical data structures<sup>2</sup> that implement the table.

`CLUSTERED` is a completely separate concept - sometimes conflated with `PRIMARY KEY`. If a table has no `CLUSTERED INDEX` and a `PRIMARY KEY` is added, then by default, that will also then be defined as a `CLUSTERED INDEX`. But this behaviour can be overridden if required, and the two really aren't tied together in practice.

---

<sup>1</sup>I actually can't think of any relevant differences at this point but this is just to avoid nitpicking, hopefully.

<sup>2</sup>The clustered index and any non-clustered indexes and statistics.

Comment: In fact the basic UNIQUE definition in Standard SQL forces NOT NULL, too: *Without Feature T591, “UNIQUE constraints of possibly null columns”, in conforming SQL language, if
UNIQUE is specified, then the <column definition> for each column whose <column name> is contained
in the <unique column list> shall contain NOT NULL.*

Answer (score 1):

`PRIMARY KEY` does not allow null and has to be unique, constraints `NOT NULL UNIQUE` also may apply the similar rule into the column as `PRIMARY KEY` does, however, your table can only have one primary key, but could have multiple `NOT NULL UNIQUE` Columns.

and by `NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` and `PRIMARY KEY`, both will be stored, ordered, and structured as in the CLUSTERED INDEX, so in operational performance basis for select, insert, update, or delete, there should be no different

the only difference might be on the metadata itself.